# Native code in C++/CLI DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I would like to be as close to real time as possible, so my intention is to have the most critical part of the code unmanaged (I don't want GC to block execution). So I tried this:

```
class Native 
{
public:
    int GetValue() 
    {       
        return 1;
    }
};

ref class Managed 
{
public:
    void Test() 
    {
        Native n;
        Console::WriteLine(n.GetValue());
    }
};
```

ILDASM shows Native::GetValue compiled to IL. Is it possible to keep this class/function unmanaged? Is a dedicated unmanaged dll the only way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I need #pragma directives:

```
#pragma unmanaged

class Native 
{
public:
    int GetValue() 
    {       
        return 1;
    }
};

#pragma managed

ref class Managed 
{
public:
    void Test() 
    {
        Native n;
        Console::WriteLine(n.GetValue());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

C++-CLI are managed extensions that allow you to directly use .NET functions such as `Console.WriteLine` that you have shown in your example. It is compiled into a managed assembly. If you want unmanaged code you will have to instruct the compiler to produce unmanaged code. But in this case obviously you will have to forget about the .NET functions.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to combine managed and unmanaged code in the same DLL.

Comment: Yes, but the resulting assembly will be managed and thus handled by the CLR which is what I thought you wanted to avoid in the first place. That's exactly what C++-CLI is useful for: easily port some existing native code to the managed platform.

Comment: As it was said previously I just need to keep some classes/functions unmanaged because of performance considerations.

Comment: Then, as I said in my answer, you have to instruct the C++ compiler to produce native/unmanaged code. And also for this to work youhave to remove all .NET function calls from it, otherwise the compiler will simply choke. Once you have compiled your code into a native library, you could use it from your managed code using P/Invoke.

Comment: My answer combines .NET function invocations and unmanaged fragments. As you can see we can have all in the same assembly. It was the subject of my question. Sorry if question sounds ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I probably misunderstood you requirement but I am choking on the this:

> I don't want GC to block execution

It depends on the interop scenario you are using, but in general you will not be able to prevent suspension of execution threads by simply making parts of application unmanaged. Any thread which has CLR roots along its call stack could be hijacked and halted by the GC, no matter if this thread just happens to execute "unmanaged" code.